# i have a problem with my code involving text files and checking if certain names are in it

Tags: python-3.x, text-files

I made a text file with names in and my codes works but has a big flaw i want to know if they is any way i could fix this issue.Lets say the names are 'bob' 'jim' 'mark'.If entered 'ar', it would allow you to enter since ar is in the text file. Thank you for any time.

```py
import sys

namefile=open("names.txt","r")
filenames=namefile.read()
namefile.close

if name1 in filenames:
    print("Welcome",name1)
else:
    print("ACCESS DEINED")
    sys.exit(0)

name2=str(input("What is the name of player2? "))

if name2 in filenames:
    while name2==name1:
        if name2==name1:
            print("This name is already taken, please choose another.")
            name2=str(input("What is the name of player2? "))

if name2 in filenames:
    print("Welcome",name2)
else:
    print("ACCESS DENIED")
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I answer the question, I would like to point out that the if statement you use in the while loop is unnecessary. If the while loop executes, the if is guaranteed to be true.

Now, to solve your problem, simply do this: When adding a name to the file, add a space before and after it. Then, when checking if a name is present in the file, add a space before an after the input from the user. The spaces will function as a start and end character, meaning that no "partial matches" will happen. You could also use any character's you want, rather than just a space.

I hope that this helps you moving forward!

Comment: i will try to add it

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!